# Writing large matrix using R ff

Tags: r, matrix

I've been posting about an issue over the last few days where I need to create a 7000x7000 distance matrix.  Doing it all on memory was giving me the could not allocation vector error.  I'm using Windows XP SP 3, 3GB RAM, 32-bit system.  I originally wanted to use the bigmemory library, but it appears that it is not available for Windows.  I've done some reading on the `ff package`, so this is what I cam up with so far:

```
require(ff)    
ffmat <- ff(vmode="double", dim=c(7000,7000))
ffmat <- as.matrix(dist(data[1:7000, ], diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE))
```

The problem is that I still get a vector allocation error.  Note that `dim(data)` = 7000x182 (lot's of variables).

Running `gc()` post-mortem brings the `memory.size()` back down to normal levels.  It's as if R is storing the results in memory prior to writing to the ff that was created.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: You could look into `mmap` instead of `ff`.  I've never really gotten around to looking into it but it might be worth looking into for you.

Comment: What do you expect, data[1:7000, ] is putting your ff matrix in RAM as the ff manual indicates (see ?Extract.ff).

Comment: @jwijffels Thanks for pointing that out.  However, it isn't entirely clear from the documentation how this would work on a matrix.  Let's say I write my data matrix 7000x180 to an ff object - ffmat.  I then create a second ff object using `ffmat2 <- ff(vmode="double", dim=c(7000, 7000))`.  How do I actually take the distance from my ffmat object without using RAM?  The documentation shows simple assignment from one ff object to another, but nothing regarding using outside methods.

Comment: You are asking another question than your initial question, so you need to phrase your question better to get a good answer. e.g. what do you mean with distance between 2 matrices, this is rather ambiguous and can be computed in several fashions. Have you looked at the chunking functionalities in ff?

Comment: @jwijffels I'm not calculating the distance between two matrices.  If my previous comment sounded that way, I apologize for the confusion.  I have data in a 7000x182 matrix.  The 7000 are people, the 182 are variables.  I'm attempting to calculate either a Euclidean or Gower distance between them.  If I call the `dist(..)` function for Euclidean without ff, it fails.  Ditto with `daisy(.., method="gower")`.  I can set up an `ff` object of dim(7000,7000) to hold the distance matrix.  But I can't get the data into it efficiently.

Comment: @jwijffels  I can't dump the data matrix into an ff object and then call a dist function against it.  It doesn't seem to work.  Chunk only seems to apply to dataframes.  This could potentially work, but since my goal is calculate a distance matrix, I need all pairwise distances.  I think my question is still similar.  How do I get this large distance matrix into an ff object.

Comment: Have you looked at http://rmazing.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/bigcor-large-correlation-matrices-in-r/ to see how people tackle similar problems using ff?

Comment: @jwijffels Thanks so much!  I was able to take the example from the website and contour it to my needs.  I will post a full implementation when I work out the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to jwijffels for steering me in the right direction, and to http://rmazing.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/bigcor-large-correlation-matrices-in-r/ for the start in the right direction.

Assume a 7000x180 data matrix called `training.data`. The goal is to create a symmetric distance matrix of dimension 7000x7000. In reality, using `daisy()` creates a dissimilarity measure, but it's similar logic.

```
distff <- function(training.data, nblocks=5, verbose=TRUE) {
  require(ff)
  require(cluster)
  ffmat <- ff(vmode="single", dim=c(7000,7000), filename="if so desired")
  nro <- nrow(training.data)
  ### This could be changed to handle rowcounts that have 
  ### modulus(nro/nblocks) != 0
  splt <- split(1:nro, rep(1:nblocks, each = nro/nblocks))
  COMBS <- expand.grid(1:length(splt), 1:length(splt)) 
  COMBS <- t(apply(COMBS, 1, sort)) 
  COMBS <- unique(COMBS) 
  for (i in 1:nrow(COMBS)) {
    COMB <- COMBS[i,]
    ### Since g1 and g2 get appended below, it wouldn't make sense to append the
    ### same group to itself
    if (COMB[1] != COMB[2]) {
      g1 <- splt[[COMB[1]]]
      g2 <- splt[[COMB[2]]]
      slj <- as.matrix(daisy(training.data[c(g1,g2),], metric="gower", 
                             stand=FALSE))
      ffmat[c(g1,g2), c(g1,g2)] <- slj
      rm(slj)
      gc()
    }
  }
}
```

That's it.  I realize there are some inefficiencies (like writing several of the groups multiple times).  I'm okay with that, since it works.  Like I said, the bulk of this code was borrowed and tailored from the website cited above.

Comment: Did you mean to `return(ffmat)`?

Comment: @jbaums Thanks for cleaning up the code a bit.  Negative on the `return(Ffmat)`.  Though this is a function, the function does not return a value.  It's merely writing the value `slj` to the already existing `ffmat` object at the location specified by `g1` and `g2`.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to need to break up the task into pieces and assign the individual pieces to the matrix instead of doing it all in one step.

The `dist` and `as.matrix` functions do not know that the result will be an ff object, they just try to do their part in memory.

Since the dist function does not compute distances between different sets of data it may be easiest to just calculate the distances by hand, though there may be a function in a package that will do the off diagonal distances.

Answer (score 0):

> "It's as if R is storing the results in memory prior to writing to the ff that was created. Is there any way around this?"

That's exactly what R is doing. The way your code is written does two things: it creates an `ff` object, and then it overwrites that with a traditional matrix created by `as.matrix`.

You could potentially extend the `dist` function to work with `ff` objects, or write your own implementation of `dist` that uses `ff`.

Comment: My alternative was going to be brute force. Something like: `for (i in 1:7000) { for(j in 1:7000) { ffmat[i,j] <- as.matrix(dist(data[c(i,j),]), diag=FALSE, upper=FALSE) gc() } }`  However, this seems like it would run for eternity and a day.  Would this even work?  If so, would repeated calls to `gc()` be needed...maybe just in the outer loop?

Comment: Your issue is still that `as.matrix` isn't producing an `ff` object, so you're basically still working within the constraints of R. If you want to brute force it, you'd be better served by better hardware at a minimum.

Comment: In reading the `ff` documentation, it mentions the following: "For the ’ff’ object the following class attributes are known: distance matrix c("ff_dist","ff_symm","ff")" This implies to me that it is possible to calculate the distance matrix within `ff`, perhaps using a different function.

Comment: I see that now.  However, that looks like the class inherited by the ff object created.  For instance when I create the ff object for the matrix for my raw data and then populate it with `ffmat <- as.ff(mydata)`, the classes in the `$class` attribute are `"ff_matrix", "ff_array", "ff"`.  This seems to me to imply that the ff object would inherity a `"dist_matrix"` class from a distance object.  However, I can't compute the distance matrix because of hardware limits.  Also, it threw an error when I tried `ffmat <- as.ff(dist(mydata, diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE))`  using a subset of my data.